# Android ViewPager Not working in the NestedScrollView

Tags: android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to develop collapsingToolbar with TabLayout. So I was tried with ViewPager with NesteScroolView and CollpasingToolbar, TabLayout Not showing the fragments.

If I remove the "NestedScrollView", then it is working, but if you scroll the fragment page, toolbar collapsing not working. Only CollapsingToolbar components (ImageView and TabLayout) only expanding and collapsing not ViewPager Items.

any Idea please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        >

    </ViewFlipper>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Temples"
               />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>






</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"




            android:visibility="visible"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:tabTextColor="#ffff11" />


            />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fefefe"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want like, scroll the items in the viewpager then should expand and collapse the "CollapsingToolbarLayout"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by below code

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.nest_scrollview);
        scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
```